# Reduce the space between day text and subtitle in FSCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, fscalendar

How can I reduce the space between the day text and subtitle text in FSCalendar? Below image will give you the idea:

[image]

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

I have encountered similar issues. you can do subtitleTextSize value 0 in this class **'FSCalendarAppearance'**. you should try.

Use following code:

```
@implementation FSCalendarAppearance
_subtitleTextSize = 0;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
let offSet = calendar.appearance.subtitleOffset =  CGPoint(x: 0, y: offSet)
```